# Why is に used in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

Does the particle に indicate direction in these sentences or why is it used here? Would someone be so kind to explain?

> 1. わたしはかみ**に**えがく。
>      I draw on paper.
> 2. せんせい**に**しつもんをしている。
>      I ask the teacher a question.
> 3. たんじょうび**に**たくさんのプレゼントをもらった。
>      I got a lot of presents for my birthday.
> 4. あなた**に**なにがあった？
>      What happened to you?
> 5. がっこう**に**ちこくした。
>      I was late to school.
> 6. がっこう**に**おべんとうをもっていく。
>      I'll <strike>bring</strike> take lunch to school.
> 7. これはけんこう**に**よい。
>      This is good for the health.
> 8. せんせいのしつもん**に**こたえた。
>      I answered the teachers question.

I think in case 9. に is used as a time particle. But shouldn't it be は though, like 明日は, 今年は etc. ?

> 9. ひるごはん**に**らめんをたべましょう。
>      Let's eat ramen for lunch.

Comment: I'm not sure "for" in "for lunch" indicates time in English...

Comment: I'm not sure either. Which probably means  に isn't used as a time particle here. I know that に can be used as a time particle (じゅうじ に ねる), location particle (つくえのうえ に なにがある) and direction particle (こえん に いく).